# External speaker for ICOM 2300h

Tags: resistors

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDEx6.jpg)
ICOM 2300h external speaker

I have a 2" 5 watts 8 ohms ordinary speaker, i wired them and use it as my external speaker of the ICOM 2300h.

What bothers me if I have to put a resistor with it?
If yes, what is the value of the resistor?
And where to connect the resistor from the terminal of the speaker?

Please help, with simple drawing very much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the radio has an external speaker jack, you should be able to just plug that speaker in, with no other components.

Comment: Yes did it today, and it works well, with the mono jack 3.5mm. Thank you Peter Bennet :)